# In Yocto Dunfell, which recipe is writing out `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`

Tags: authentication, yocto, systemd, tty

I would like to find the recipe writing out `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` so I can create an append.

First I tried to find out the creating package, which should be `systemd`:

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util find-path /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
systemd: /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
```

Thus, I looked up [`meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_244.3.bb`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_244.3.bb?h=dunfell) (and the [`systemd.inc`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd.inc?h=dunfell)), but didn't find anything of value. Only the following line looked like a hit:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "kmod dbus util-linux-mount util-linux-umount udev (= ${EXTENDPKGV}) util-linux-agetty util-linux-fsck"
```

This made the impression as if this file might get pulled in as a dependency, and is actually created by `util-linux-agetty`.

So I looked up the creating recipe:

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util lookup-recipe util-linux-agetty
util-linux
```

But in [`meta/recipes-core/util-linux/util-linux_2.35.1.bb`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/util-linux/util-linux_2.35.1.bb?h=dunfell) and [`util-linux.inc`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/util-linux/util-linux.inc?h=dunfell) I can't find creation of that file either.

I'm genuinely puzzled.

My image is equal to core-image-minimal except that it uses systemd as init manager.

Comment: I think they're generated by `systemd-serialgetty.bb` based on config (meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-serialgetty/serial-getty@.service).

Comment: I studied [systemd-serialgetty.bb](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-serialgetty.bb?h=dunfell) in detail, and couldn't find this happening there.

Comment: Why would systemd not own that file? In case you are expecting the file path to be listed in the recipe explicitly: FILES_* variables have default values (see bitbake.conf). One of the main package defaults is `${libdir}/${BPN}/*` which likely ends up as `/lib/systemd/*` on your system

Comment: I'll look into that. Still, altough it might be included in this recipes `FILES_*` variable, I couldn't find `getty@.service` getting installed there. That is what is puzzling me. I don't understand how this file ends up being on my image.